# WebDev VirtualBox VM, how to separate and backup

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I currently have a CentOS VM in VirtualBox with 500GB disk file, only 250GB are used.

I've started to get errors and the VM hangs indefinitely so I want to start a new Ubuntu VM and I want to keep everything separate to be able to backup things properly.

My initial thought was to install Ubuntu and all software I'll need, then take a Snapshot.

Then add a second VDI file as a disk for all the projects and data. Hopefully keeping the OS VDI as clean and untouched as possible.

Next how do I keep all projects and testing I do on the VM separate from one another?

I've thought about docker but I've never used it and I'm not sure how agile development would be, e.g. a Laravel app.

As for backups, would snapshots be enough? I can probably find a 1TB HDD around if needed.

Edit:

Is there any downsides to having one or the other (beside taking more space I guess):

- Container-webapp-1
- Container-webapp-2
- Container-mysql
- Container-apache

vs

- Container-webapp-1
- Container-webapp-2
- Container-mysql-webapp-1
- Container-mysql-webapp-2
- Container-apache (I guess I could split this too but I don't see why)

Comment: One question per post please. Also, open ended "are there any downsides" sorts of questions don't work well here. They aren't bad questions, they just don't fit our "single specific question that can get a single specific answer" method here, and may be a better fit on a forum where open ended discussion is the norm.